# Как минимизировать сетевые издержки?

Tags: windows, многопоточность, ассемблер, сеть

Пишу программу. её задача проверить наличие файла на сервере в локальной сети
Язык ассемблер, ОС винда 32бит. Файлов много, надо сделать как можно быстрее.
Пока лишь додумался разбить задачу на 4 потока
Поиск произвожу функцией GetFileAttributesA

Comment: А рассматривался ли вариант, что бы заслать на нужные сервера своего клиента, который все файлы поищет и потом отчитается?

Comment: Если файлы находятся в одной директории, то по идее имеет смысл получать список ("итератор") файлов функциями `FindFirstFile`/`FindNextFile`, а в этом списке уже проверять наличие нужного файла.

Comment: На ассемблере? Если вы уверены, что сможете ускорить сложный сетевой код, написав его на ассемблере, вы сами себе злобный буратина. Пишите на высокоуровневом языке, затраты на работу стандартной библиотеки ничтожны по сравнению с сетевыми задержками. Не устраивайте себе бег с препятствием на ровном месте.

Comment: Весь "сложный" сетовой код это вызов GetFileAttributesA из Kernel32.dll, да разбитие на четыре потока

Comment: Файлы находятся в разных директориях.

Comment: "А рассматривался ли вариант, что бы заслать на нужные сервера своего клиента, который все файлы поищет и потом отчитается?" Скажите как это сделать? Я просто не знаю как

Comment: ничего сложного - пишется программа, которая умеет искать файлы локально. Она также на определенном порту открывает сокет и ждет команд. Клиент подключается к серверам и отдает их команду на поиск нужного файла. Сам протокол работы по сокеты можно как ручками написать, так и использовать что то готовое (например xmpp/irc/zeromz).

Comment: Вы изобретение себе дыру в безопасности)

Answer (score 3):

Один из способов уменьшить сетевые издержки — это выполнять запросы в "пакетном режиме". В данном случае, вместо того, чтобы проверять каждый файл по отдельности, надо отправлять в одном запросе сразу множество файлов и получать их статусы в одном ответе.

Более сложный способ — асинхронная модель и буферизация. В этом случае отправляемый запрос и получаемый ответ — отдельные сообщения, которые не связанны потоком исполнения. Это позволяет прозрачно буферизировать сообщения (собирать в кучку, возможно сжимать, и отправлять разом) по объему и-или времени. Впрочем, в случае TCP/IP буферизация уже и так делается системой — поэтому достаточно отсылать запросы и обрабатывать ответы асинхронно, или в разных потоках исполнения. В качестве иллюстрации можно посмотреть на картинку [HTTP pipelining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:HTTP_pipelining2.svg) — учитывая, что там порядок ответов фиксирован, а в общем случае он произволен.

В любом из этих подходов приложение разбивается на серверную и клиентскую часть. И `GetFileAttributes` выполняется (должен выполняться) на стороне сервера, а не на стороне клиента.

Comment: Можно какой0нибудь пример, не знаю. На форте?

Comment: А как доступен сервер для запуска серверной части? По SSH или через PSExec, или еще как-то?

Comment: Не шарю в этом С компа обращаюсь по АйПи 11.123.23 , к примеру

Comment: Тогда изучайте матчасть. Т.к. способ неприменим, если нет доступа к командной оболочке сервера.